# ASP .NET MVC controller model parameter is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

**The ultimate goal I want to achieve is to get MULTIPLE PARAMS from HTTP POST request, so if you know any other methods of doing it, please inform me.**

I am using

- ASP .NET self-hosting MVC, latest version.
- localhost
- attribute mapping_ for routing
- some chrome extension for POST message tests, and I didn't forgot to add `Content-Type: application/json` to the header!

First code I tried looks like below:

```
[RoutePrefix("report")]
public class DefaultController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost, Route("error")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Echo(string uid, string buildNumber, string log,
        string stack, string context, ...)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("received message: ");
        Console.WriteLine(" uid: " + uid);
        Console.WriteLine(" buildNumber: " + buildNumber);
        Console.WriteLine(" log: " + log);
        Console.WriteLine(" stack: " + stack);
        ...

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

But if i try to access `http://localhost:XXX/report/error`, which is routed to controller, I got following message:

`No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI`

I somewhat figured out that for POST message I have to use single parameter (is this real??) using Model, so I added a model named `ReportModel` and revised it as follows:

```
[RoutePrefix("report")]
public class DefaultController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost, Route("error")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Echo(ReportModel report)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("received message: ");
        Console.WriteLine(" uid: " + report.Uid);
        Console.WriteLine(" buildNumber: " + report.BuildNumber);
        Console.WriteLine(" log: " + report.Log);
        Console.WriteLine(" stack: " + report.Stack);
        ...

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

Now I am getting `null` value for parameter `report`. Please help me to figure out how to get multiple parameters in HTTP POST.

**[(maybe?)RESOLVED]**

RAW data seems like below:

```
POST /report/error HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:10999
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache

{ "Uid":"asdf", "BuildNumber":"qwer", "Log":"hoo", "Stack":"asdfasdf", ...
```

And I was sending in a '*form-data*' tab in Postman Chrome extension, which fails to work over and over again. **Then I changed to 'raw' tab, then it just works fine.**

I still don't know what was the problem. But still, thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Another alternative is [FormCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Web.Mvc.FormCollection%29%3Bk%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2%29%3Bk%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true), but this is more for when you don't have a fixed model.

Comment: What does the actual POST look like?

Comment: The first thing to check is your POST body with Fiddler. Also the ReportModel class must have public properties for de-serialisation.

Comment: @Padraic I forgot to mention I've done it!

Comment: @ParkJongBin Can you post your answer for others if you have resolved it.

Comment: @Liam Could you tell me how the raw POST should looks like?

Comment: @JamieKeeling I didn't resolved this problem yet, but sure I will if I found the answer.

Comment: Using [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) is the easiest way to get this. Install it, run it, fire your HTTP POST and you'll be able to view it in fiddler. Add this to the question and it'll help people help you.

Comment: Glad you resolved it. For future reference: If you use the form-data tab on Postman it automatically overwrites your Content-Type header to multipart/form-data

Comment: @NilsO Thank you so much! I finally figured out what was going on.

Comment: Now that you know about Fiddler you´ll have an easy time inspecting future requests to make sure they look as you expect :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that your data structure being posted to the Web API action matches that of the model.

To aid in your debug efforts, you can install a Nuget package called [Swashbuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle). Swashbuckle documents your current MVC/Web API based controllers and actions, taking into account the input and output of each. The best part (and the bit which should help you the most) is that it provides a UI for you to test each action, even going as far to create the data structure required based on the structure of your action parameter.

Installing the package creates a route (e.g. http://myrooturl/swagger) for you to access the UI itself, so there is no configuration needed as it works out of the box.

If you can hit your API action using it and the parameters are populated, then your manual method of creating the POST is at fault. If for some reason it still fails, then at least you have a method of self documentation as the Swagger UI will keep the list of actions up to date automatically.

Answer (score 0):

you need to configure your web API route to accept a ReportModel parameter.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "newont",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{ReportModel}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Controllername", ReportModel= "ReportModel", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }}
            );
```

[For more info](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Attribute%20routing%20in%20Web%20API)

Comment: I'm using attributes for routing (like `httpConfig.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();`). Do I still have to configure routing  explicitly? I want to deal with codes without `MapHttpRoute()` function.

Comment: @ParkJongBin no need to add both

Comment: And actually routing is working. I can attach debugger on controller code, and there's where I found `report` parameter is null.

Comment: @ParkJongBin at the time of posting it self your ReportModel object may be null

Comment: What do you mean by 'at the time of posting itself'? The time when parameter `report` was null is at the start of the function call, and I expect POST call should be parsed already at that time.

Comment: form where you are posting Report-model object to your web api check weather there exists values for your Object Properties

Answer (score 0):

When using an API its good practice to use a Model for multiple Parameters.

If you are using Javascript you build the object up using the same names in your Model and they will map across on the request.

Also if you needed the same data back to manipulate the front end you can build up an object and return it like so

`return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, myObject);`

Comment: Just to add to this: I see your model's properties are CamelCased and the parameters you receive are not; the mapping is case sensitive.

Comment: Model has CamalCased Properties, and I also changed my HTTP POST sender to send CamalCased keys.

Answer (score 0):

you can call the post method from jquery and pass the parameters in the data field.

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: "report/error",
    type: "POST",
    data: { uid: "1", buildNumber: "123", log ="log string", context = "context", stack = { property: "value"} },
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, p3, p4) {
        var err = "Error " + " " + status + " " + p3;
        if (xhr.responseText && xhr.responseText[0] == "{")
            err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).message;
        alert(err);
    }
});
```